# How do you replace the class of a Maven dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

There is a class in a maven dependency that is incompatible with Java 8.

How do you properly fix that problem?

Right now I'm doing the following:

1. Create a package with the same name
2. Create a class with the same name in that package
3. Copy and paste the code
4. Fix the incompatible API call

The problem is that this class contains API calls to restricted classes and although I changed the Eclipse compiler settings (Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Error/Warnings -> Deprecated and restricted API -> Forbidden reference (access rule): Error -> Warning) to allow access the project will only compile sometimes. If it doesn't compile I'll get a "can't find symbol" error.

Edit:

Here are the details you asked for:

- Dependency: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.wss/xws-security/3.0
- Class: EncryptionProcessor
- Necessary change:

  ```
  // Change line 1053 FROM: 
  // _dataEncryptor = XMLCipher.getInstance(dataEncAlgo, _dataCipher); 
  // TO:
  _dataEncryptor = XMLCipher.getInstance(dataEncAlgo);
  ```

Edit-2:

Maven build error:

```
 [ERROR] symbol:   class XMLCipher
 [ERROR] location: class com.sun.xml.wss.impl.apachecrypto.EncryptionProcessor
 [ERROR] /C:/Users/{name}/development/eclipse_workspace/git/xws-security/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/wss/impl/apachecrypto/EncryptionProcessor.java:[1482,98] cannot find symbol
```

Comment: Is the dependency which contains the incompatible a project of your own or your company? Please give us some code and error messages

Comment: classes are loaded via the class loader which follows the classpath. Inside a webapplication you can place patch classes inside WEB-INF/classes - those come first. If not in a webapp create a jar with that class and pass it first to the java process: java -cp my-patch.jar:original.jar - it is a bit smelly to patch stuff since its difficult to maintain and deploy applications like this. One often forgets about the patch and what is was for and so on. If the sources are available for that class I would rather create a patched artifact based on them.

Comment: How do I do that? (Sources are available here: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.wss/xws-security/3.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General solution:

- download all project sources
- apply your modification
- - use version control so that change isn't lost
- change version in `pom.xml`, for example from `3.0` to `3.0-patched`
- launch maven build
- copy generated artifacts to you repository/Artifactory, if you use one
- change dependency version in your own project

Comment: Unfortunately I could not download the _complete_ sources for the project. But I did something similar. I made a new maven project "xws-security-java8-patch", included xws-security-3.0 as dependency, added only the broken class and fixed the bug. Now I include xws-security-java8-patch instead of xws-security-3.0 and it works like a charm.

Comment: I added a detailed explanation of the steps I did in a separate answer.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a detailed guide describing what I did exactly:

1. Create new Maven project in Eclipse
2. Configure Maven settings of new project (Important: Use the same group and artifact ID and only change the version number)

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
       <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
       <version>3.0-java8-fix</version>

       <properties>
           <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
           <java.version>1.8</java.version>
       </properties>
   </project>
   ```
3. Add dependency of bugged JAR

   ```
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
           <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
           <version>3.0</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                 <artifactId>xmldsig</artifactId>
                 <groupId>javax.xml.crypto</groupId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                 <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                 <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   ```
4. Create Java file in the same package of class that needs to be fixed

   ```
   package com.sun.xml.wss.impl.apachecrypto;

   public class EncryptionProcessor {
       // The FIX goes here
   }
   ```
5. Add Maven shade build plug in to handle creation of patched JAR file (this is not the only plug in to handle this kind of task - e.g. dependency:unpack)

   ```
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <!-- plug in for creation of patched JAR file -->
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.1</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>shade</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <filters>
                               <filter>
                                   <artifact>com.sun.xml.wss:xws-security:3.0</artifact>
                                   <includes>
                                       <include>**/*.class</include>
                                       <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                   </includes>
                                   <excludes>
                                       <exlude>
                               com/sun/xml/wss/impl/apachecrypto/EncryptionProcessor.class
                                       </exlude>
                                   </excludes>
                               </filter>
                           </filters>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
6. Include patched JAR in other projects as necessary (Note: If you experience ClassNotFoundExceptions or similar errors do this: Right-click on the project -> Properties -> Maven -> "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects":false)

In case you are not familiar with Maven. Here is the complete pom.xml: http://pastebucket.com/88444

Answer (score 8):

Similar to Steve S.'s answer, but using the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). Based on [this blog post](http://gochev.blogspot.de/2014/07/patching-maven-library-with-your-custom.html).

I changed the name of the patched library (not the version), but it depends on your needs what works better for you.

The dependency on the original library should be marked as `<optional>true</optional>`. Otherwise, the projects that depend on your patched library will also depend on the original library, which means that both the patched and the original version will be on the classpath, which can lead to all kinds of problems.

If your project is a child project, you can still use a completely different groupId and version than your parent pom. Doesn't matter.

You can exclude the classes you patch from unpacking, but it's probably not necessary, because Maven will first unpack the original library and then compile your new version, which means that the original classes are overwritten. Nice!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!-- remove this if you don't have a parent pom -->
  <parent>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.company</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-bar-patched</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.6</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
                  <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                  <!-- excludes are probably not necessary -->
                  <!-- <excludes>**/Foo.class,**/Bar.class</excludes> -->
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.6</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: I use Intellij idea to compile, but Maven says "No sources to compile". Not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This answer should really be a comment on Steve's own answer, but I do not have enough reputation points to write comments.

Steve's own answer won't work, because

```
<filter>
    <artifact>com.sun.xml.wss:xws-security:3.0</artifact>
    ...
</filter>
```

is an invalid reference, that the shade plugin won't be able to resolve. According to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html), the artifact composite identifier takes the form: `groupId:artifactId:type:classifier`, i.e. you cannot specify a version.

You may leave out the version specifier (which is not understood anyway), but the filter will then apply to the dependent artifact as well as the build artifact, and you will either miss some files in the package, or the shade plugin will issue warnings about overlapping classes and resources in the two artifacts.

A work-around may be to rename your artifact, e.g. `<artifactId>xws-security-java8-fix</artifactId>`, so it won't clash with the dependency. Then you may rename the result artifact back with the following configuration sections on the shade plugin:

```
<shadedArtifactId>xws-security</shadedArtifactId>
<shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
```

You probably also want this:

```
<promoteTransitiveDependencies>true</promoteTransitiveDependencies>
```

This solution is usable. But it is not very satisfactory, since the changing artifact ID confuses Maven, so Maven cannot resolve the artifact before it is installed.

By the way, installing such an artifact is also not straight forward. This use of the install plugin may do the trick:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <goals><goal>install</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>custom-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals><goal>install-file</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <file>${project.build.directory}/xws-security-${project.version}-shaded.jar</file>
                <pomFile>${project.basedir}/dependency-reduced-pom.xml</pomFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Because I needed to do this and couldn't do what user:158037 claims, based on steve-s answer's and yours, I wrote a small POC that would do something like this in two ways: either including the shaded class in the project that uses the dependency, and making an intermediate jar that shades the class and that the final project would use (more like discussed here). It's in xunqueirax/shade-plugin-poc at gitlab.com, in case useful to sb. However, I don't understand the problems you mention about the install phase. You do have to install the dependency first somehow, but isn't that usual stuff?

Comment: @GabrielXunqueira, I should have explained the install issues in detail, since now I honestly don't remember exactly what problems I encountered. But I think there are two problems: First, the normal install goal would install the build artifact under the name "xws-security-java8-fix", which is inappropriate, when you want to replace the original artifact as a transitive dependency via dependency management. And second, the normal pom would depend on the original artifact, that we want to replace; the dependency reduced pom doesn't.