# Error while getting SecretKey from EncryptedKey (JRE7 to JRE8 Upgrade)

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I've upgraded a spring application from Java 7 to Java 8 which contains encrypted webservices. If i run a soap-call with a test, i get the following Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
    <faultstring xml:lang="en">com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Error while getting SecretKey from EncryptedKey; nested exception is com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Error while getting SecretKey from EncryptedKey</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

When I take a look into the catalina.out, see the following stacktrace:

```
16-Nov-2017 15:54:48.109 SEVERE [tomcat-http--4] com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.KeyResolver.getKey WSS0284: SOAP Fault Exception Occured
 com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Error while getting SecretKey from EncryptedKey
        at com.sun.xml.wss.core.EncryptedKeyToken.getSecretKey(EncryptedKeyToken.java:78)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.KeyResolver.processSecurityTokenReference(KeyResolver.java:719)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.KeyResolver.getKey(KeyResolver.java:135)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.apachecrypto.DecryptionProcessor.processEncryptedData(DecryptionProcessor.java:494)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.apachecrypto.DecryptionProcessor.decryptReferenceList(DecryptionProcessor.java:339)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.apachecrypto.DecryptionProcessor.decrypt(DecryptionProcessor.java:143)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.EncryptionFilter.process(EncryptionFilter.java:421)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processWSSPolicy(HarnessUtil.java:81)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processDeep(HarnessUtil.java:252)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityRecipient.processMessagePolicy(SecurityRecipient.java:849)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityRecipient.processMessagePolicy(SecurityRecipient.java:801)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityRecipient.validateMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:242)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.XWSSProcessor2_0Impl.verifyInboundMessage(XWSSProcessor2_0Impl.java:134)
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor.validateMessage(XwsSecurityInterceptor.java:163)
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.handleRequest(AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.handleRequest(DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:227)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:176)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:89)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
```

I've tried to update or exclude some wss-libraries, but no effect.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Edit: There will be another Exception thrown with a wrong CipherMode comming from JVM. So a look into the runtime-source shows, that the algorithm between jdk 7 and jdk 8 was changed. in jdk 7 you can run without any CipherMode provided, only a log-entry will be made. In JDK 8, a correct ciphermode is mandatory, otherwise there will be an exception thrown. So no, I need to find out how to change the CipherMode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i've resolved the problem.

There were some changes in JRE 8, which are incompatible to xws-security.
I've had to patch the classes EncryptedKeyToken and EncryptionProcessor to JRE 8 changes and it seems to work fine.

The changes are very small:

**com.sun.xml.wss.core.EncryptedKeyToken**

```
// Starting line 69
xmlc = XMLCipher.getInstance(algorithm);
xmlc.init(XMLCipher.UNWRAP_MODE, null); // First, init with opMode UNWRAP
// leave the next lines
```

**com.sun.xml.wss.impl.apachecrypto.EncryptionProcessor**

```
// changingline 1053
// _dataEncryptor = XMLCipher.getInstance(dataEncAlgo, _dataCipher);
_dataEncryptor = XMLCipher.getInstance(dataEncAlgo);
```

Patching with maven can be looked up here:

[How do you replace the class of a Maven dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740919/how-do-you-replace-the-class-of-a-maven-dependency)

For replacement, I've used the following pom:
https://pastebin.com/iYcAkpmH